# Flexslider as field

Tags: entities, javascript

I have the following requirement and i wanna know the best approach for it
I have a content type that has a field of multiple images. Is there a way to make these images appear as a slideshow when that node is viewed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [Field Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow).

This project provides a Slideshow formatter for Image fields, using JQuery [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin.

It builds the slideshow from a single node, with a multi-valued Image/Media/Field Collection field.

Comment: You are right my friend. I tried Field Slideshow module and it seems to be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

For that use the [Views Galleriffic](https://drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic) and the documentation is [click here](https://drupal.org/node/758724)
and a simple tutorial is [here](https://drupal.org/node/1578774)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexslider or any other view filters as field by installing the EVA (https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module in Drupal. The EVA (Entity Views Attach) will create a pseudo-field that you can attach to any entity and use it as if it was a field.